# Difference between Phaser and CyclicBarrier

Tags: java, java.util.concurrent

I stumbled upon a doubt regarding a difference between CyclicBarrier and Phaser utilities in Java concurrent package.

I understand that CyclicBarrier allows group of threads to wait until all threads arrive at a specific point. Phaser also do same but it supports multiple phases.
I also understand that, a **CyclicBarrier can be reused.** I think this reuse facility **makes its function same as Phaser**.

Consider following programs:

**Testing Phaser :**

```
import java.util.concurrent.Phaser;

public class PhaserTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Phaser p = new Phaser(3);
        Thread t1 = new Thread(() -> process(p), "T1");
        Thread t2 = new Thread(() -> process(p), "T2");
        Thread t3 = new Thread(() -> process(p), "T3");
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        t3.start();
    }

    private static void process(Phaser p) {
        try {
            System.out.println("Started Phase 1: "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
            p.arriveAndAwaitAdvance();
            System.out.println("Finished Phase 1: "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
            System.out.println("Started Phase 2: "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
            p.arriveAndAwaitAdvance();
            System.out.println("Finished Phase 2: "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
        } catch(Exception e) {}
    }

}
```

**Output:**

```
Started Phase 1: T1
Started Phase 1: T2
Started Phase 1: T3
Finished Phase 1: T3
Started Phase 2: T3
Finished Phase 1: T1
Finished Phase 1: T2
Started Phase 2: T2
Started Phase 2: T1
Finished Phase 2: T2
Finished Phase 2: T3
Finished Phase 2: T1
```

**Testing CyclicBarrier:**

```
import java.util.concurrent.CyclicBarrier;


public class CyclicBarrierTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        CyclicBarrier cb = new CyclicBarrier(3);
        Thread t1 = new Thread(() -> process(cb), "T1");
        Thread t2 = new Thread(() -> process(cb), "T2");
        Thread t3 = new Thread(() -> process(cb), "T3");
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        t3.start();
    }

    private static void process(CyclicBarrier cb) {
        try {
            System.out.println("Started Phase 1: "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
            cb.await();
            System.out.println("Finished Phase 1: "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
            System.out.println("Started Phase 2: "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
            cb.await();
            System.out.println("Finished Phase 2: "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
        } catch(Exception e) {}
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Started Phase 1: T1
Started Phase 1: T2
Started Phase 1: T3
Finished Phase 1: T3
Started Phase 2: T3
Finished Phase 1: T1
Started Phase 2: T1
Finished Phase 1: T2
Started Phase 2: T2
Finished Phase 2: T2
Finished Phase 2: T3
Finished Phase 2: T1
```

In PhaserTest and CyclicBarrierTest, next phase is not started until all parties arrive/completes the previous phase.

**So, what's the benefit of having Phaser ?**

Comment: The main difference is that a `Phaser` is advancable.

Comment: @Ben Advancing a phaser causes it to be usable again for blocking the threads. The same is supported by CyclicBarrier without need of any advancing.

Answer (score 5):

Phaser comes from [JSR-166](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=166)

> When comparing phasers to existing Java features, it is explained that
>   similar functionality to the CyclicBarrier class is supported
>   (introduced in Java 5), but phasers are inherently more flexible:
>
> The [java.util.concurrent] CyclicBarrier class supports periodic barrier
>   synchronization among a set of threads. Unlike Phasers, however,
>   CyclicBarriers do not support the dynamic addition or removal of
>   threads; nor do they support one-way synchronization or split-phase
>   operation. One of the main motivators for exploring additional barrier
>   implementations was not just to have increased flexibility, but also
>   to increase performance and scalability of the barrier synchronization
>   concept:
>
> Performance results obtained from a portable implementation
>   of phasers on three different SMP platforms demonstrate that they can
>   deliver superior performance to existing barrier implementations, in
>   addition to the productivity benefits that result from their
>   generality and safety properties.

full explanation here:
https://www.infoq.com/news/2008/07/phasers

Also another comparing article defining `Phaser` as `CyclicBarier+CountdownLatch`:
http://flex4java.blogspot.com/2015/03/why-and-how-to-use-phaser-in-java.html